# Regular expression to obtain lat/lng from a string

Tags: php, regex

I have a string in this format.

"1784_Anarchy+Brew+Co~Unit+5+Whitehouse+Farm+Centre~Stannington~Morpeth~NE61+6AW_^55.13033~-1.702607"

Would the pattern look something like

```
preg_match_all("\^d+\", $map, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

so the lat -- \^d+.d+ ?
the lng -- \~d+.d+ ?

trying to get the lat and long values --
lat: 55.13033
lng: -1.702607

Comment: what are you  trying to get form the string?

Comment: preg_match_all('((?:\d+)(?:\.\d*)?)', $map, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);  -- fetching all the numbers

Comment: 55.13033  and -1.702607

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If lat and lng string position remain constant, here is a quick way around it. else post other instances

```
$str = '1784_Anarchy+Brew+Co~Unit+5+Whitehouse+Farm+Centre~Stannington~Morpeth~NE61+6AW_^55.13033~-1.702607';

 preg_match_all("/(?<=[\^|\~])\-?([\d\.]+)/", $str, $matches);
 $lat = $matches[0][0];
 $lng = $matches[0][1];

 echo "lat: $lat, Lng: $lng";

 //output: lat: 55.13033, Lng: -1.702607
```

Comment: well -- its dependent though on the address field being the same -- they have a ^ and a ~ near the coordinates is there no way to tap into that

Comment: -- so here you have 1784 -- but what if there next address - doesn't have a unit 5

Comment: i dont see 1784-- but you can always match ^ and ~

Comment: yeah - it was ok - but it has failed on another string. 1399_Anchor+Springs+Brewery+Company+Ltd^The~11D+Lineside+Way~Lineside+Industrial+Estate~Littlehampton~BN17+7EH_^50.815639~-0.554158

Comment: -- maybe we should look at this backwards -- if its a case of checking for the LAST 2 numbers of the array

Comment: $reversed = array_reverse($matches[0]);


 $lat = $reversed[1];
 $lng = $reversed[0];

 echo "lat: $lat, Lng: $lng";

Comment: "/(?<=[\_|\^|\~])\-?([\d\.]+)/"  -- done - this works now -- had to go with an _ for some cases

Answer (score 0):

the following regex expression should isolate coordinates:

```
(-?\d{1,3}\.)\d{5,6}
```

The block inside () will match an optional '-' for negative LAT/LONG followed by group of 1 to 3 digits ( as longitude can be up to 180) followed by a 'dot'.

The rest of the expression will match from 5 to 6 digits ( as per the precision that seem to be in your example ).

As long as the search string keep more or less like the one stated, this should work:

[image: Demo]

Hope this helps !!

Comment: does this capture the polarity of the value?